# VSTS query field value was ever not blank

Tags: azure-devops

We are trying to track blockers in VSTS work items. We have a field, Blocked Reason, with a drop down list for values that we want to report on. My question is how we query to find work items that have ever been blocked (by the end of an iteration a task will likely no longer be blocked so we can't just use the current status).

The query interface has an operator 'was ever' but how do I specify a value of 'not blank'?

[image]

This would show us all the tasks that were blocked at some point.

Comment: Does the value `Not Blank` exist in the field `Blocked Reason` drop down list?

Comment: No - not blank is not a value. It's a concept - I want to find things that ever had any value. How can I do that please?

Comment: Ok, add changed the solution to query the Blocked Reason field was ever Not blank/empty. You can find the detail in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

To query the tasks which have blocked (before or now), you can add clauses which **`Was Ever`** operator for each `Blocked Reason` field drop down value (use **Or** among the drop down values causes). So the editor should be:

[image]

You should group the clauses for the Blocked Reason field drop down values. The way to group the related causes as below:

Select `Blocked Reason` field drop down values with `Was Ever` operators -> group selected clauses -> query.

[image]

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing something like this but I guess it would work. Raised suggestion on user voice: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/31831774-add-not-blank-as-a-value-option-in-queries